# Object Data Type in AS3 and Flash Builder 4.5.1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, sprite

I am trying to save a Sprite object as a file on the device I'm working on and it seems to work. the problem I'm having is reading the saved file back and placing it back on stage as a sprite. Below is the code I have so far, could someone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong? I have a suspicion that the saved isn't what I expect it to be since the file sizes have been under a kilobyte.

```
public function save_album(e:Event):void
{
    var outFile:File = File.documentsDirectory; // dest folder is desktop
    outFile = outFile.resolvePath("canvas3.bin");

    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    //trace (File.documentsDirectory.url + "/canvas2.bin");

    fs.open(outFile, FileMode.WRITE);

    bytes.writeObject(graffitiContainer) //graffitiContainer is a Sprite
    bytes.position = 0;

    fs.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    fs.close();
}

public function open_album(e:Event):void
{
    var inBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var inFile:File = File.documentsDirectory; 
    inFile = inFile.resolvePath("canvas3.bin");  // name of file to read
    var inStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    inStream.open(inFile, FileMode.READ);
    inStream.readBytes(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length);
    inStream.close();
    inBytes.position = 0;

    ui.removeChild(graffitiContainer);

    var obj:Sprite = inBytes.readObject() as Sprite; //returns a null


    graffitiContainer = obj;
    ui = new UIComponent();
    graffitiContainer.x = 0;
    graffitiContainer.y = 100;
    ui.addChild(graffitiContainer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish; however, this implementation doesn't do what you're thinking - writeObject could only serialize general public properties, and not the graphics member.

You could render it to a Bitmap.

Saw a blog post about this:
http://jacwright.com/201/serializing-display-objects/

Comment: thanks, what I want it to save the actual object as a file in local storage so when I open it later I can edit and make changes to it, by rendering it to bitmap data I wont be able to edit the layers I have in it.

Comment: You would have to write a custom serialization of the graphics data along with general DisplayObject properties, recursively for children as well.  Have you written an editor for these objects, or how do you intend to edit the objects in the Flash Player runtime?

Comment: I've already written code to handle all children etc in my Sprite container, draw methods and shapes... I just need to find a way I can save the sprite in a binary or similar format so when I retrieve it I can retain the structure.